# ArrayOutOfBoundsException: asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-bytecode-asm

I have a hierarchy with the following dependencies:

```
Base(Timer timer)

    Timer(PublisherService service, BaseDao userDao, DataProcessor processor)
```

There are additional dependencies within `DataProcessor` but I will not go that far because it seems my error occurs a lot earlier. In correspondence with that dependency graph, I have the following Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="base" class="com.apps.consumer.Base">
    <constructor-arg name="timer" ref="consumerTimerTask"/>
</bean>

<bean id="consumerTimerTask" class="com.apps.consumer.ConsumerTimerTask">
    <constructor-arg name="service" ref="tradePublisherService"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    <constructor-arg name="consumerDataProcessor" ref="consumerDataProcessor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tradePublisherService" class="com.apps.consumer.common.TradePublisherService"/>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.apps.dao.UserDao"/>

<bean id="consumerDataProcessor" class="com.apps.consumer.ConsumerDataProcessor">
    <!-- Additional constructor-args here for this guy -->
</bean>
```

At the top level of my application, I will run:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-configuration.xml");

Base consumerBase = context.getBean("base", Base.class);
```

As I follow the debugging I find that the `Timer` is initialized successfully. . .somewhat. Before the `Timer` is fully resolved and injected into the `Base` I get back the following:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3145
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.visitConstructor(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:123)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:89)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:886)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:600)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:886)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.apps.Main.contextInitialized(Main.java:39)
```

I'm tracing it back as far as `Main` which is the only class in the stack trace that is mine.

Removing all three constructor parameters in both Java and XML resolves the issue however introducing any one of the 3 constructor arguments brings it back. The dependency graph does go a little deeper for `DataProcessor` for example, but even if I just use `BaseDao` as the constructor args, which itself has no dependencies, I will get this error.

Any idea what is going on here? I have tried various permutations of constructor args, creating new interface implementations in case something in my existing ones was causing the issue to bubble up, pretty much everything shy of just rewriting this from scratch more carefully.

EDIT:

```
public class Base {
    private TimerTask consumerTimerTask;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Base.class);

    public Base(TimerTask timer) {
        this.consumerTimerTask = timer;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the timer.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void initialize() throws Exception {
        final int updateFrequency = 10000;

        // Once all fields have been generated and prefs read, initialize the update process every number of seconds.
        final Timer updateTimer = new Timer();

        updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this.consumerTimerTask, 0, updateFrequency);

        logger.info("Base initialized successfully!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `Base`.

Comment: Added code for `Base`

Comment: What are your Spring and Java versions. Google: *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)*. Your problem is related to byte code manipulation of the framework.

Comment: This was the issue, I was working with inherited code and `Spring` was in version 3 updated to the latest and now it works.

Comment: You could answer your question to detail the solution for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being that the code was inherited, I overlooked the version of the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Setting `<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>` fixed the issue.

Comment: What was the version before. What are your other depndencies? What is your Java version ?

Comment: Previous version was `3.1.0.RELEASE` with Java version 1.8

Comment: In which xml file ?

Comment: @Siddharth pom.xml (maven config file).